# No sound in KUbuntu 14.10, only Dummy output device listed

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, mute

My sound card is "Game Theater XP 5.1".

This command:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Gives:

> Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-cs46xx snd-ac97-codec snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
>
> Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-cs46xx snd-ac97-codec snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.

So it seems ok to me.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

This is the output of the second command (in english, thanks for your comment):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  pulseaudio-module-x11
Suggested packages:
  apmd alsa-oss oss-compat pavumeter paman pavucontrol paprefs
  pulseaudio-module-raop pulseaudio-esound-compat
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  alsa-base pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/895 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4419 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Selecting previously unselected package alsa-base.
(Reading database ... 142700 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../alsa-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pulseaudio.
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio_1%3a4.0-0ubuntu22_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio (1:4.0-0ubuntu22) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pulseaudio-module-x11.                  
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio-module-x11_1%3a4.0-0ubuntu22_amd64.deb ...   
Unpacking pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:4.0-0ubuntu22) ...                           
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...                                  
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.8-1ubuntu2.1) ...                             
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...                             
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot                                    
Setting up alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4) ...                                 
Setting up pulseaudio (1:4.0-0ubuntu22) ...
Adding user pulse to group audio
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back     to defaults
update-rc.d: warning: stop runlevel arguments (1) do not match pulseaudio         Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.8-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:4.0-0ubuntu22) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-10ubuntu2.1) ...
```

I noticed these errors:

```
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
update-rc.d: warning: stop runlevel arguments (1) do not match pulseaudio Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
```

Comment: Small hint: you can change most commands to English output by prefixing `LANG=C`, for example `LANG=C apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Temüjin from ubuntuforums.org this issue has been solved! Temüjin wrote:

The needed firmware files used to be a part of the kernel, but got moved out for legal reasons in kernel 3.14:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/co...c207f46cbcae03

This should fix you (reload alsa or reboot when finished):

```
cd ~
wget ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/firmware/alsa-firmware-1.0.28.tar.bz2
tar xjf alsa-firmware-1.0.28.tar.bz2
cd alsa-firmware-1.0.28
./configure
cd cs46xx/
make
sudo make install
```

Perfect! A little difference only: wget downloaded the compiled files also so the make command wasn't necessary